# JQuery $.post() with array and/or receiving array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I want to ping servers and get the online status of that server with JQuery $.post() method.
My current code:

**JQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.post('php/ping_server.php', { 'domains[]': ["example.com", ..., ...] }, function(status) {
        for (var i=0; i < status.length; i++) {
            $('.sidebox .onlinestatus').eq(i).addClass(status[i]).text(status[i]);
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

**PHP:**

```
include('functions.php');

if (isset($_POST["domains"])) {
    $status = array();
    foreach($_POST["domains"] as $domain) {
        $status[] = pingDomain($domain);
    }
    die(json_encode($status));
}
```

The function pingDomain() returns "Offline" or "Online" and it works.
I'm not getting any errors or warnings in the console but nothing happens...

What is wrong?

Comment: ``'domains[]': ["example.com", ..., ...]`` is wrong do ``'domains': ["example.com", ..., ...]``

Comment: @Ehsan: I replaced it but nothing changed - not working, no errors

Comment: `console.log(status)` in you jquery recieve method, then tell us if it prints what it should.

Comment: @kajacx: thats strange - it doesn't print anything on the console...

Comment: Are you using your browser developer tools to inspect the requests and see what's sent and what's responded?

Comment: And what do you see? Are the fields sent like you expect? What about the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need use the proper header in the php, like

```
include('functions.php');

if (isset($_POST["domains"])) {
    $status = array();
    foreach($_POST["domains"] as $domain) {
        $status[] = pingDomain($domain);
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); // here 
    die(json_encode($status));
}
```

or *parse* the response in JS like

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.post('php/ping_server.php', { 'domains': ["example.com", ..., ...] }, function(status) {
        status = JSON.parse(status); // here
        for (var i=0; i < status.length; i++) {
            $('.sidebox .onlinestatus').eq(i).addClass(status[i]).text(status[i]);
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

*Note: both because you have specified the expected datatype explicitly.* otherwise not needed.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that.
So if I leave out the datatype in the $.post()-method I can only do the JSON.parse in JQuery?

I'll test it as soon as possible (database down).